# Wrong value INSERTED using teradata stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, insert, teradata

I have a stored procedure where I explicit trap a particular error, i.e invalid Emp Name.

When this occurs I set the **`MESSAGE_TEXT`** and **`SQLSTATE`** to specific values.

The **`EXIT HANDLER`** then exits and displays the **`SQLSTATE`** & **`MESSAGE_TEXT`** to the caller of the stored procedure. This is want I want to happen, and it works as expected.  However, I also insert a row into a Log table as part of the **`EXIT HANDLER`**, and for some reason, the value that gets inserted into the Log table has extra characters appended at the end, i.e.

> ***Invalid Employee Name providedee Name provided***

instead of

> ***Invalid Employee Name provided.***

If I hardcode the message into the Log table it works, but I don't want to do that.  The message to the caller of the stored procedure works correctly.

***Reference Code Below***

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE SecAppl.Create_User_SL
(p_UserName CHAR(7)
,p_Password VARCHAR(30)
,p_EmpName VARCHAR(70) /* First Name then Surname */
,p_EmailAddr VARCHAR(100)
)

BEGIN

 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
   BEGIN
    SET vSQL_ERR_CDE = SQLCODE;
    SET vSQL_STATE = SQLSTATE;
    SET vSQL_ERR_MSG = '';
    GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1  vSQL_ERR_MSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;

    INSERT INTO Log_Table
       VALUES (p_UserName, 'SQLEXCEPTION' , :SQLCODE, :SQLSTATE, vSQL_ERR_MSG, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);         
    RESIGNAL; -- Send message back to caller of Proc
  END;  

 IF p_EmpName = ''
   THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE 'U0001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Employee Name provided';
END IF;

END;
```

Any assistance would be great.